# Как создать календарь на основе StringGrid в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Как создать календарь на основе StringGrid в Delphi?...

Answer (score 4):

1. Берете дату соответствующую первому числу интересующего месяца при помощи `EncodeDate()` и кладете ее в переменную `StartDate`.
2. Выясняете на какой день недели падает первое число при помощи функции `DayOfTheWeek` и сохраняете результат в переменную `WeekDay`.
3. Берете `StringGrid` шириной 7 столбцов. В цикле от `1` до количества дней в месяце (можно получить функцией `DaysInAMonth()`) заполняете `StringGrid` числами, начиная с первой строки и столбика `WeekDay`. После записи очередного числа увеличивайте `WeekDay` на один. Когда `WeekDay = 7`, сбрасываете его в ноль и переходите на следующую строчку `StringGrid`-а.

PS. На всякий случай: [справка по работе с датами](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/navDateUtils.php.html).

Comment: Хорошо написал молодец. Хотя некоторое время назад для этих целей использовал tDrawGrid.